# How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: test (class file version 52.65535) was compiled with preview features that are unsupported?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I recieved this error when I trying to debug a java program with vscode:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
test (class file version 52.65535) was compiled with preview features that are unsupported. 
This version of the Java Runtime only recognizes preview features for class file version 55.65535
```

Here is launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Launch) - Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Launch)-test",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the version of java:

```
java --version:
openjdk 11.0.2 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.2, mixed mode, sharing)

javac --version:
javac 11.0.2
```

This program can run on ubuntu original terminal, but throws error in vscode.

it would be greatful if you can help me out.

Comment: Don't compile with `--enable-preview`. If you do compile that way, you must also specify that option when running the code.

Answer (score 2):

In launch.json file, add "vmArgs": "--enable-preview" to your debug configuration.

```
{
   ...
   "vmArgs": "--enable-preview"
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a clean install of jdk1.8.0_202. I deleted all other JRE versions, and cleaned up my PATH variables and set my JAVA_HOME to the correct path. I get the rocket and thumbs-up in the VS Code status bar, but when I press F5 on a simple Hello World using code basically created by VS Code, I get the same first half of your error, but mine ends in "... has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 52.65535)" - same number! Is this a VS Code issue? adding "vmArgs": "--enable-preview" did not fix.

Comment: @AppDreamer Yes, the flag doesn't work for JDK 8, that's a bug in the java extension. And the latest redhat.java@0.42.1 extension has fixed the issue. Suggest update the extension and have a try.

Comment: Jinbo, I installed 1.8.0_196 and backed out 202, and it fixed my problem. Perhaps it was just an issue with 202 on JDK 8.

Answer (score 2):

Update: after intensive googling I think I found the answer:

**This is due to a mismatch with the code version that's compiling in vscode and the JDK version you're running in your system.**

1. In your VScode, your compiler is trying to compile using (class file version 52.65535), which is **Java 8**, meanwhile your system is running class file version 55.65535 which is **Java 11**. In this case, clean uninstall the Java 11 in your system first, follow the uninstall instructions here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html#A1096903
2. After uninstallation, download and install the JDK 8 from oracle:
   https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
3. reopen your vscode project, do the following:
4. open your launch.json file, add this line in configuration:

   "vmArgs": "--enable-preview"
5. inside your file your want to compile and run, press F1 in vscode and do the following:

   - Java: Clean the java language server workspace
   - Java: Force Java Compilation
6. Press F5 your code will compile and run!

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/java-lang-unsupportedclassversion

Answer (score 1):

The same error on the Intellij idea maven build. correct the JRE version of Maven to the correct version of java.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by compiling the class through the terminal itself with javac in the "src" folder and then replacing the ".class file" in the "bin" folder by the ".class file" created in the "src" folder. I believe the problem is in VSCODE, I did the same test in Eclipse and it worked without problems.

Another alternative:

in the configure Java Runtime option of VSCODE, you have the option to choose the Runtime version we can choose which java version we want to use, mine was 19, however, apparently it does not work well, so I changed it to version 17 and everything works perfectly. There is an option to download the latest version of the JDK and it is not in 19 only 17 as shown in this print from the website https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/java/java-project/download-jdk .png that is exactly the same as what appears in the program. Until then it was the best alternative I found