# How to fix launch LinkageError in Eclipse when trying to build and run the simple program?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been trying for the past couple of hours to configure Eclipse IDE and get it work, but I am not able to find out what is wrong.

I've been trying to change many settings inside of IDE but I was still unable to make it work and compile the program.
My wanted Java version to install is Java SE 15.

How can I resolve this?

While trying to build simple console program I am getting following error:

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class org.sun.dem15
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for org/sun/dem15 (class file version 59.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'
```

UPDATE OF THE QUESTION:

After making changes to:

Project ---> Properties ----> Java Compiler and using --release option and enabling preview feature for Java 15 I got next error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'demo'.
Provider "jar" not found
```

Comment: Can you show the program you're running?

Comment: @CodingNinja https://imgur.com/a/HtFiwv3

Sorry if image is too small I'm on RDP connected to person's TeamViewer

Comment: @CodingNinja I was following this peron's tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcM1acdAUjw 
First time I got it running, and there was problem with --release thing I couldn't select it, after that I changed something and then I got --release thing selectable and checkable, but then this error started to occure... That something was showed me as an error to be configured rightly and I simply clicked on paths and edited things in those paths... Can't remember what exactly did I touched...

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55447687/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-test-class-file-version-52-6

Comment: @CodingNinja That wouldn't help. I guess I am just going to do clean reinstallation and seting up of Eclipse IDE over again...
Rather that then spending 3 hours more and breaking my head through the wall

Comment: Java 15 requires Eclipse 2020-09 with [this plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-15-support-eclipse-2020-09-417). Can you confirm that you have this?

Comment: Yes I have that one @howlger 
Btw. Still after full reinstalling I get same error

Comment: Which versions exactly of Eclipse, of the plugin and of Java? Does it work with Java 11 or 14?

Comment: Eclipse version 2020-09 (4.17.0)
Java SE 15

Btw. Can you check on my post up here I did UPDATE:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was the most stupid thing in the world actually! And thing I would never suspect.
Somehow Java SE 15 got problem, it "wasn't" installed on computer, even though I had directory in Program files which included all Java files(even the java wasn't installed)...

So you can check this actually by going into command prompt and typing: `java -info` and if you get:

```
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

than the problem is your Java file isn't installed.

Also there's command `javac -info` and if you get same thing printed out in console still you don't have java se installed.

Comment: I suspected it was a problem with the download as i eluded to in my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're compiling the program in 1 version of java and running it in another. I would recommend uninstalling java altogether and reinstalling the latest version.

Press windows key, type in add or remove programs. search for java and uninstall it. Then go to oracle to reinstall java and follow the directions there. You may find more info here: [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: test (class file version 52.65535) was compiled with preview features that are unsupported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55447687/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-test-class-file-version-52-6)