# UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for <class> (class file version 60.65535)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

```
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Java version: 16.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

I start my Spring app via `mvn spring-boot:run`. Now everytime I change a file on the classpath, the server restart fails:

Output

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.2)

2021-07-22 15:48:03.648  INFO 9756 --- [  restartedMain] de.xehpuk.foo.Application                : Starting Application using Java 16.0.1 on XEHPUK with PID 9756 (C:\Users\xehpuk\ws\foo\target\classes started by xehpuk in c:\Users\xehpuk\ws\foo)
2021-07-22 15:48:03.649  INFO 9756 --- [  restartedMain] de.xehpuk.foo.Application                : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-07-22 15:48:03.817  WARN 9756 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [de.xehpuk.foo.Controller] for bean with name 'controller' defined in file [C:\Users\xehpuk\ws\foo\target\classes\de\xehpuk\foo\Controller.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for de/xehpuk/foo/Controller (class file version 60.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'
2021-07-22 15:48:03.821  INFO 9756 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-07-22 15:48:03.838 ERROR 9756 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [de.xehpuk.foo.Controller] for bean with name 'controller' defined in file [C:\Users\xehpuk\ws\foo\target\classes\de\xehpuk\foo\Controller.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for de/xehpuk/foo/Controller (class file version 60.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
        at de.xehpuk.foo.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [de.xehpuk.foo.Controller] for bean with name 'controller' defined in file [C:\Users\xehpuk\ws\foo\target\classes\de\xehpuk\foo\Controller.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for de/xehpuk/foo/Controller (class file version 60.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1545) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:686) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:536) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:208) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
        ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for de/xehpuk/foo/Controller (class file version 60.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:512) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:420) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:414) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:413) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.findClass(RestartClassLoader.java:160) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:142) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:466) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:469) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1607) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1534) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
```

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>de.xehpuk</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have to stop the server, `mvn clean` and `mvn spring-boot:run`. What's wrong here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55447687/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-test-class-file-version-52-6

Comment: @LMC My error message is different (not a version mismatch). And I don't understand where I enabled preview features.

Comment: [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52232682/2834978) how to enable in maven.

Comment: @LMC I don't want to enable preview features.

Answer (score -1):

Seems a preview feature is enabled in your code somehow

Add the following as compiler options. So in the compile time, your ide will display the warnings and classpath of the used preview feature

`-Xlint:preview`